# How to acces each same indexed cells on two Dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have a df1 dataframe :

```
| A | B | C | D |
|---|---|---|---|
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
```

and a df2 dataframe :

```
| A | B | C | D |
|---|---|---|---| 
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
```

And I would like that if a cell in df2 is less than 5, then set its equivalent in df1 to 0.

The result should look like this :

```
| A | B | C | D |
|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 4 | 8 |
| 0 | 0 | 6 | 8 |
```

Is there any other solution than iterating on each row and each column ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [masking](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking):

```py
mask = df2 < 5
df1[mask] = 0
```